# Browser waiting for connection forever

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to fix a Asus Notebook with Windows 10 installed. The problem is that no browser connects to internet. The browser gets stuck on "Waiting for {website}" and just waits for the connection forever or says "{website} took to long to answer". I have the same issue in both Chrome and Edge.

I am connected to the internet with wifi, and the connection is working. I can confirm that by Spotify working and playing music online. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Related question [Connected to wifi but browser doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/1260305/connected-to-wifi-but-browser-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

#### Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`